# how to allow all wildcard string to the routing url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I'm developing a laravel API.so when during the implementation i face some problem in the  passing the parameters to the routing URL.
i have to pass to parameters ,one is sessionId and other one is userid.
my session id like this,

> eyJpdiI6uiIkF6TElTNVp1YW5BajltytytyydMVGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYuiuiuiu081NTdyTTFVemNWSWFNaE1NSmV2STAziXTuiuiuiuiZFiuuNUE9PSIsIm1hYiuiuiuiyI6IjJkNjJjNGNlNWU5OTUxZWUwMDRlMzI2YTViMGY0MDFiuiuiumNmI5ZmU2NWU2ZuiuiuiuiM3MWJiZDU2ZWVkYzFiMWI4OGJjNWMifQ%3D%3D

So this session id contains a-z,A-Z,.,etc and all wildcard strings (%3D%3D) congaing this string

I've try lots of ways to  to pass that sessionid string to the my get function.but still no any proper solution to me.

this is my code segment ,
routes.php

```
$api->version('v1',function ($api){
$api->get('OneU/{Id?}/{UserId}',[
    'as'=>'user',
    'uses'=> 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@show'])
    ->where(['Id' => '.[a-zA-Z1-9\-_\/?;!"`\'()`\|{}]+']);
 });
```

this is my controller class code segment

```
  public function show($id,$userid)

{
    //  $id='SessionId';
    try{

    $user=DB::table('users')->where('SessionId',$id )
                            ->where('UserId', $userid )
                            ->get();
        if(!$user)
        {
            return response()->json(['null'],404);
        }
        return $user;

    } catch (Exception $exception)
    {
        return response('something bad',500);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `->where(['Id' => '.[a-zA-Z1-9\-_\/?;!"`\'()`\|{}]+'])` in the route. You can validate it in the controller instead.

Comment: yeh i tried it,when i validate it in the controller I've use like operator,when i use it show lots same outputs.i want to get exact one search result